# Printing dictionary without brackets in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
if len(inventory) == 0: 
    print("\nThe current inventory does not contain any journals!\n")
else:
    print("\nComplete Inventory:\n===================")
    for key in inventory:
        print(key+":")
        for char in key:
            print("-", end='')
        print()
        for id in inventory[key]:
            index = find_index(archive, id)
            print(archive[index], ("\n"))
```

Printing out results enclosed in [] and '''s, unsure how to remove the square brackets and apostrophes, any help much appreciated

Comment: Is it simply that you don't want any square brackets or apostrophes at all? In that case, just convert to a string before print, then replace square brackets and apostrophes with empty strings.

Comment: @Kytuzian removing all [] and ''

Comment: use for-loop to print elements from dictionary/list, or use `", ".join(archive[index])` (if `archive[index]` is a list) to create string before you print it.

Comment: show some example data in `inventory` and `archive` so everyone could run code and see problem.

Comment: yes. I agree with furas. show some example data.  so everyone could run code and see problem. –

Answer (score 3):

If you are simply just trying to find out how to get rid of the brackets, try using `.strip("[]")`

For apostrophes, you can try using `.replace("'","")`

Or if you want, you can just use `.replace()` to replace the brackets too, but it's up to you. I find these ways to be the most efficient.

Comment: `print(archive[index].strip("[]"), ("\n"))` is giving an error?

Comment: which kind of error? Also, i suggest putting all of it in parenthesis and then try .strip() and .remove()

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: try changing the list to a string using str(archive[index])

Comment: I thought I tried that! Mustve made an error earlier. That fixed the [] much appreciated

Comment: print(str(archive).strip("[]").replace("'","") + '\n')  to get rid of the apostrophes too

Answer (score 1):

I find it helpful to  use

```
 .strip('[]')
```

See more at Documentation
https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html